# DataForm and 2nd Level Object Binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, telerik, caliburn.micro

I am using Telerik's WPF controls with Caliburn.Micro.  In particular the DataForm control.  I am trying to bind it to an object that has the following make up.

```
public class FrequencyMap : BindableBase
{
    private Guid id;

    public Guid ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string procedureCodeId;

    public string ProcedureCodeId
    {
        get { return procedureCodeId; }
        set
        {
            procedureCodeId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private FrequencyChoice frequency;

    public FrequencyChoice Frequency
    {
        get { return frequency; }
        set
        {
            frequency = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private DateTime effectiveDate;

    public DateTime EffectiveDate
    {
        get { return effectiveDate; }
        set
        {
            effectiveDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private DateTime? terminateDate;

    public DateTime? TerminateDate
    {
        get { return terminateDate; }
        set
        {
            terminateDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and then the `FrequencyChoice` object looks like this:

```
    public class FrequencyChoice : BindableBase
{
    private int id;

    private string modifiedUser;

    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string code;

    public string Code
    {
        get { return code; }
        set
        {
            code = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string calculationDescription;

    public string CalculationDescription
    {
        get { return calculationDescription; }
        set
        {
            calculationDescription = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private DateTime inactiveDate;

    public DateTime InactiveDate
    {
        get { return inactiveDate; }
        set
        {
            inactiveDate = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string ModifiedUser
    {
        get
        {
            return this.modifiedUser;
        }
        set
        {
            this.modifiedUser = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

This works quite well except for the `Frequency` property.  How do I get that to work properly.  Do I have to use an `Enum` like this article? [Data Forms in your XAML](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/13-05-02/data-forms-in-your-xaml-lob-apps-got-you-down-let-raddataform-create-your-ui!)
If so how would I link the two?

Comment: I have Telerik suite but haven't used DataForm yet - will check it out and see if I can provide an answer as I'm getting fed up of laying out grids :) (you didn't find the answer yet did you?)

Comment: No, haven't got it yet.  I'd love to hear what you find.

Comment: I guess the frequency choice should be a multi-select dropdown with multiple `FrequencyChoice` objects in it? Or should they be editable? Can you explain a bit more where the data for this class comes from (does it load from pre-defined values or is the user supposed to edit it on screen?)

Comment: Sure.  It could be though that isn't the direction I was going.  Basically there is a table in the DB called FrequencyMap that has an ID, ProcedureCodeId, and FrequencyId.  The ID is "throw away" and the table is just meant for me to pull a ProcedureCode from with all "possible" Frequency Choices.  That make ANY sense?

Comment: Sort of, what do you expect the user to see in the interface?

Comment: I was just going to have the DataForm control show it one row at a time.  so they would select a ProcedureCode from a dropdown and then a FrequencyChoice from another and then Save.

Comment: Ok sounds like you want to use the dataformcombobox type and bind the list to itemssource and the selected item to DataMemberBinding. You'd have to load the collection of frequency choices into the vm first. Are you using auto generate for the fields in the form?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is 1 Frequency Map with Many FrequencyChoices relationship

1st I would change the property to inherit from PropertyChangedBase

```
 public class FrequencyChoice : PropertyChangedBase
 {
 }
```

then change your properties as below

```
 private BindableCollection<FrequencyChoice> frequencyChoices;
    public BindableCollection<FrequencyChoice> FrequencyChoices
    {
        get
        {
            return this.frequencyChoices;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, this.frequencyChoices))
            {
                return;
            }
            this.frequencyChoices = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.FrequencyChoices);
        }
    }
```

I am not really sure what is BindableBase (from google is Prism but hey ur using Caliburn so use PropertyChangedBase) but if want to still use it go ahead but just make sure it handle change notification for you

as each map has many choices you will need collection to store the choices